# Python: add a variable to a list with an if-statement

Tags: python, list, variables, if-statement

In python add a variable to a list in an if statement.
I want to do something like this:

```
var = 1
vars = []

if var >= 1:
  # add it to "vars"
  pass
```

Comment: append is the first function which shows up on the list documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method

```
var = 1
vars = []

if var >= 1:
  vars.append(var)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just adding a single element:

```
var = 1
vars = [var] if var >= 1 else []
```

It seems more logical that you would have many vars in some container so a list comp would be better:

```
vars = [1,2,1,2,4]
new_vars = [var for var in vars if var >= 2 ]
```

Comment: Naw, not like that. Had a doubt that this was that famous addition (to compete with C's ternary operator)

Answer (score 1):

```
var = 1
vars = []

if var >= 1:
  vars.append(var)
```

Comment: Append adds to a list.